# Is there a way of searching div element by class in GAS?

Tags: html, xml, google-apps-script

I'm trying to get value from a website. I know I can use `getDivById()` method:

```
var spage = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://website.com/page?search='+latest).getContentText();
var sdoc = XmlService.parse(spage);
var found = getDivById(sdoc.getElement(),'the-id');
```

...but the website does not use IDs in the divs.

Is there something like `getDivByClass()` method, or what is the correct way of searching for div by class in **Google Apps Script**?

Comment: In HTML a `class` is an attribute of an element. So try to find some method in `XMLService` that allows you to fetch div elements by attribute.